# Unable to load JSON (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

I'm trying to load a JSON file by link and then align data (like title, date etc) to variables so I can use them. Right now, I don't care about variables.  I just want to alert() them but something seems like I'm doing it wrong, alert returns nothing!

I use JSfidle to run the code. The code is this:

```
var JSON_unparsed = $.getJSON('http://www.14deftera.gr/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json') ;

var JSON = JSON.parse(JSON_unparsed) ;

alert(JSON.feed.entry[0].title.$t) ;
```

The URL I want to parse is: http://www.14deftera.gr/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json

and here you can see the JSON how is structured if that can help you:

[image: JSON structure]

Comment: First of all, `$.getJSON` is ***asynchronous***. Secondly, the URL can't be loaded, as it's not JSONP or have CORS headers, and therefore is in violation of the same-origin policy.

Comment: Don't name the variable `JSON`.

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: I used this and still nothing : var raad = $.getJSON('http://www.14deftera.gr/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json') ;

var rad = JSON.parse(raad) ;

alert(rad.feed.title.$t) ;

Comment: Both comments are relevant. If you overwrite JSON with the parsed JSON  you'll never be able to use JSON.xxx in a meaningful way. But the first comment explains why it doesn't work the first time.

Comment: can someone fix the code ? i am not a professional and that problem just  stops me from finishing a project. thanks

Comment: It can't be fixed, the data you're trying to get ***can not be gotten*** with a browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSONP` for this:

**Update**, for better understanding how to work with returned JSON.

```
var id, title;

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.14deftera.gr/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json', 
    jsonp: "callback",    
    dataType: "jsonp"  
}).done(function(r){
    // r is returned JSON
    for(var i in r)    
        // for ex ID is this
        id = r[i].id.$t;
        // and title
        title = r[i].title.$t;
        // and so on, check the json, I mean check the browser console by hitting F12, below code will print the whole JSON 
        console.log(r[i]);
});
```

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/m-dehghani/pen/grXrrp?editors=0010

Comment: where can i see the output ?

Comment: edit : i mean, how can i add the output to variable ?

Comment: within `for` statement, the `r` is `returned JSON`, edit the code to `console.log(r[i]);` to see all the values. remove the `if` too

Comment: @RadwanAhmet check the pen please

Comment: @RadwanAhmet worked? if so, please mark as answer, for other readers, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adeneo's reply, in your code, JSON_unparsed variable is holding something called (differed or promise object), this object might be holding the data inside it,but you are using the wrong way to pull it out. in  order for you to get it out, you need to call (.done()) function, see the below:

```
var JSON_unparsed = $.getJSON('http://www.14deftera.gr/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json').done(function(json){
console.log(json);
console.log(json.feed.entry[0].title.$t);
});
```

aside from that, if you got an error with something like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.14deftera.gr/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json&_=1459788714707. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

it means that you are not allowed to call this API/URL from your current domain.

One more thing, if you are using getJSON method, there is no need to parse the returned data, jquery will parse it for you

Comment: thanks! But i still have a problem, I dont know what i am doing wrong, but still doesnt working. http://i.imgur.com/83T2IF8.png

Comment: @RadwanAhmet, $ is not defined error means that either you didn't include jQuery library, or you didn't wrap your code within the ready function: 

$(function(){});

it would be better if you used jsfiddle to post your code so we can help you better.

Mehdi's reply below is fine, I visited his codepen and it seems that he forgot to attach the jQuery library, once I did so, it worked just fine.

Comment: now i puted the jquery i found this code nice too. but how can i attach the output to a variable ?